# Arango query I have it working in the shell but can't getting working in Arango/Foxx

Tags: arangodb, foxx

```
db.broad_broad.byExample({"location":"space_1"}).toArray()
```

with my database this returns

```
[ 
  { 
    "_id" : "broad_broad/416394873974", 
    "_key" : "416394873974", 
    "_rev" : "554852115738", 
    "location" : "space_1", 
    "space_1" : { 
      "players" : { 
        "2" : [ 
          "ninja" 
        ] 
      } 
    } 
  } 
]
```

after many hours can make this happen in Foxx

Comment: What actually is happening when you are running the above query in Foxx? Are you getting any error messages and which? Or were you just looking for a way how to run the query from inside a Foxx route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not sure if i understand the question correctly so let me repeat it in my words:
You have the query

`db.broad_broad.byExample({"location":"space_1"}).toArray()`

which is working in `arangosh` as expected.
Then you copied it to a Foxx app and it is not working, correct?

Most likely it is a missing `require` for the internal db module, which is always loaded in the shell, but not loaded in the Foxx environment.

The following minimal Foxx App should work for your example:

```
var db = require("internal").db; // Mind this line here
var Foxx = require("org/arangodb/foxx");
var app = new Foxx.Controller(applicationContext);

/** Short description
 *
 * Long description.
 */
app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
  var result = db.broad_broad.byExample({"location":"space_1"}).toArray();
  res.json(result);
});
```

If this does not solve your issue is it possible to you to find the error message in the server log to help me debugging?